# Logic App - Twitter trigger issue: Create and authorize OAuth connection failed

Tags: azure, twitter, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a simple Logic app with Twitter trigger "When a new tweet is posted".

**My steps:**

1. Add a trigger in designer
2. Connection name - TwitterConnector
3. Authentication Type - Use default shared application
4. Click "Sign in"
5. Authorize MS Azure Logic app to access my account

**Result:**
I got a message "Create and authorize OAuth connection failed":
[Create and authorize OAuth connection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqMfO.png)

If I save Logic app and run it, I get error message 400 Bad request:

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Key 'Token' in connection profile is not valid.\r\n inner exception: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\nclientRequestId: 245d0f38-5f84-412d-bd20-d53c197488b7",
"error": {
"message": "Key 'Token' in connection profile is not valid.\r\n inner exception: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0."},
"source": "twitter-ase.azconn-ase.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue to resolve it i did the following steps:

1. Changed my twitter app access to **Elevated**
2. Setup user authentication settings in the twitter app:
   App Permisions: Read and Write
   Type of app: native
   Call Back URI: https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect
3. Deleted previous api connections of the logic app present in the resource group.
4. Selected **Bring your own application** in the authentication mode of logic app and entered the twitter api key and secret in the consumer key and secret.
   After this i was able to login.

Just to be on the safer side I enabled pop-ups, allowed all cookies, cleared browser history, cache, passwords and had logged in to twitter developer account in the same browser later.

Comment: I did everything, I now have less hair. Tried your callback URL. Bingo! Worked.

Answer (score 0):

We have created a consumption based logic app in our local environment with Twitter trigger "When a new tweet is posted".

Twitter trigger in logic apps  supports two authentication types to create an connection.

- Use default shared application
- Bring your own application

Tried creating a connection using the authentication mode as  `Use default shared application` connection creation got failed.

Using `Bring your own application` authentication mode we are able to create the connection by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/twitter/#creating-an-oauth-client-application-in-twitter) documentation & authenticate to it successfully.

> Key 'Token' in connection profile is not valid.\r\n inner exception: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Based on the error message , we have gone through couple of [Microsoft community blogs](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Action-When-a-new-tweet-is-posted-failed/m-p/872337#M21891) suggested  workaround is **to delete the current connection, clear the cache of your browser and try creating a new connection**.

If you still faces the issue we would suggest you to open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/) or please create a technical support ticker by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.